# Add separator Spinner items

Tags: android

I am using the following code to display a spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapterFetching = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner, new String[]{"Fetching..."});
RouteSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapterFetching);
```

layout.xml

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/Spinner_Routes"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#002361"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

spinner.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#002361"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
```

How can I get a separator line between the items ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"//change the size for thickness
    android:background="#000"/>//change accordingly for color
```

below this

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#002361"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
```

in spinner.xml